# Entity Framework - Separate Model For Each Table is necessary?

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework with MVC structure for a project of mine.

As EF manages all database related changes and on "Update Model From Database" we are getting up to date model.

So Do I need to create Separate model.cs class for each of my Table to Use it as a object and Set Value into that.

To be more specific,
The whole project is having all operations using Ajax call.
In those Ajax call I am passing values to data in a JSON from.

Now, At controller level I need to retrieve the value from that JSON.
For that How Can I use my Entity Model for particular Table ?
Do I need to create model for every table ?

Can't Models be generated for each table automatically?

Updated:
Reference Code Added.

```
1.
Let's say 
I have a table Student with , StudentID INT, ClassID INT , Name VARCHAR().
2.
Here is the JavaScript Code
    function AddStudent() {
    var data = { "ClassID": 1, "Name": 'ABC' }

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Admin/AddNewStudent',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (ServiceResponce) {
             refreshgird();
        }
    });
}

    3.
    StudentController.cs

    public JsonResult AddNewStudent(Student obj)
            {
                try
                {
                    var add = db.AddNewStudent(obj.ClassID, obj.Name).ToString();
                    return Json(add, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return Json(ex.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }

4. Student.cs
 public class Student 
    {
        public int ClassID{ get; set; }

        public string Name{ get; set; }
    }
```

> My question is by creating Student.cs model I am following correct way or not ?

Comment: I just want to know that If we have TableName.cls files in our Model Folder with EDMX, That is good practice or not ?
If not Please let me know the way to avoid that.

Comment: Did you try to create EF model and context using the built in template offered by visual studio? That will create necessary classes for you to use directly. Now to show data it is recommended that create viewmodel classes based on what data you want to show. One viewmodel can represent only on db class or can combine more than one db classes. If you have views to perform CRUD only on one db class then one -to-one viewmodel makes more sense.

Comment: So I need to use "SpName_Result" classes generated by EF to make it work in my case , Right ? Which Build Template you are telling about , Is it T4 ?

Comment: "SpName_Result" looks like class generated for output of stored procedure. Why you want to edit the output of stored proc. Anyways if that's your requirement then then yes you need go that way. You can get lot of example MVC application with EF online which you can use to get start with your project.

Comment: I see those examples and run my applications too. I want to know that if I am utilizing the features of EF.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I don't want to create manual classes for each table. So are those created Automatically (Or any way to do so) ?

Comment: If you can some of your code, like data model classes, view model classes, controller etc would help to see if you have done it right.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I just updated the question. pls have a look at that

Comment: I have a few questions about the code but discussing about them here would not appropriate as it is already suggesting to move this discussions to chat. Let me know if you want to take this further on private chat.

Comment: where is your controller code for [httppost] request? further you need not to create any models for entity framework you can directly deal with the database using EF

Comment: That's the only Code I have written. I got my answer that I need not to write any model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If your EF model is included in the MVC project I would say no you do not have to create separate models for each entity - just use the ones created by EF.
2. If your MVC project is split into a Data, Domain and Presentation layers (projects) you can separate the generated data classes from the EDMX (in the Data layer) and have them generated in the Domain layer. See Plural Sight training by Julie Lerman "Getting Started with Entity Framework 5" "Separating Generated Domain Classes from the EDMX file" chapter.
3. If you are a purist then you should have at least 3 layers (Data, Domain and Presentation) and the Domain objects should not be the ones generated by EF.  They should be customized to the applications needs and loaded from the EF objects as required.